# PyQt file browser - how to work with that file?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pypdf

I am writing my first app in python using pyqt5. My all icons and main scrips are working correctly, I have all modules imported. Now I need to connect everything together. Here I have the biggest problem. When i click on icon it open file browser; then I click on .pdf file and ... here I would like to my program to run  def dzielenieStron()
but it crashes my program. I have tried many different solutions but still do not find an answer, here is part of code which doesn't cooperate:

```
 def openFile(self):
        self.fileName = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Wybierz plik')
        self.name = open(fileName, 'rb')
        self.dzielenieStron()

    def dzielenieStron(self):
        ReaderSplitPage = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(self.name, 'rb')
        for page in range(ReaderSplitPage.getNumPages()):
            p = ReaderSplitPage.getPage(page)
            WriterSplitPage = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
            WriterSplitPage.addPage(p)
            with open('page-%02d.pdf' % page, 'wb') as f:  # Tworzy nazwy plikow po kolei
                WriterSplitPage.write(f)
```

**Of course all line are on same level. I do not why here it is changed...**

I would be thankful for your tips

Comment: `fileName` or `self.fileName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
def openFile(self):
    pathFileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Wybierz plik', '', 'pdf(*.pdf)')   
    print("pathFileName-`{}`, \n_-`{}`".format(pathFileName, _))
    if pathFileName:
        print("Wybrany plik: ", pathFileName)
        f = open(pathFileName, 'rb')
        self.dzielenieStron(f)

def dzielenieStron(self, f):   
    with f:
        ReaderSplitPage = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f, 'rb')
        for page in range(ReaderSplitPage.getNumPages()):
            p = ReaderSplitPage.getPage(page)
            WriterSplitPage = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
            WriterSplitPage.addPage(p)
            with open('page-%02d.pdf' % page, 'wb') as f:  # Tworzy nazwy plikow po kolei
                WriterSplitPage.write(f)
```

Comment: thank you. It works. I am trying to understand your code, 'pathFileName, _ ' - '_' - it refers to last value?
'print("pathFileName-`{}`, \n_-`{}`".format(pathFileName, _))' -it is complicated for me,  is it working with dictionaries?

Comment: String Formatting https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting